# Why is a certain font (Oswald) not appearing in Scribus?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, scribus

I installed the [Oswald font family](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oswald) using Skyfonts. I can use it e.g. from LibreOffice. But it does not appear in Scribus. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scribus needs a line in the font configuration file (Fontconfic) for each separate font storage folder.

Font hiring services make crypted and hidden storage folders into your system. The fonts are taken into use via special server program that tweaks the system to make the hired fonts visible for those programs who ask them in system's way.

Scribus has its own way that bypasses the system and that makes it incompatible.

Comment: Indeed, the ttf-files were just downloaded into `%AppData%\Monotype\skyfonts-google`, selecting them and right-clicking to choose Install... copied those to `C:\Windows\Fonts`. Now they are selectable in Scribus. Perfect.

Comment: @MSC Actually I believed it much harder, because those who try to make money by hiring fonts should have a  motive to disable all easy hacks. Actually I'm not sure if your hack works after your license expires because I'm not a competent system specialist, only an user. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @MSC ,,,continued: I do not know into where in the system the license inspector is added. If you also do not know, you take the risk that after you do not pay any more you have non-working font files that are difficult to find and remove.

Comment: The fonts are free. I do not expect any problems.